# Set awk output to variable in fish shell

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gawk, fish

I am using `fish` shell and I can't seem to set the output of `awk` to a variable.

```
set installed_version (scala -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{ print $5 }')
```

Any ideas why that's the case?

**Edit:** This works though

```
set foo (java -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1{ print $3 }')
```

Comment: How are you determining that the variable is not being set?

Comment: What's the output you get from running simply `scala -version` ?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish By echoing the value of the variable. The output of `scala -version` is `Scala code runner version 2.11.5 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL`. And it's not just Scala. I have a similar command for SBT which is also not working.

Comment: Try experimenting redirecting the output various ways: `scala -version >/dev/null`, `^/dev/null`, etc, to determine which stream it's really on.

Answer (score 4):

`scala` is going into the background, starting a REPL because it thinks stdin is a terminal.  This works for me:

```
set installed_version (scala -version 2>&1 < /dev/null | awk 'NR==1{ print $5 }')
echo $installed_version
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [fish bug #1949](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1949) - fish doesn't run command substitutions in a subprocess, and so leaves stdin connected to the tty. Because of that, some tools don't behave as the should.

Joe Hildebrand's workaround (explicitly redirect `</dev/null`) is the right thing to do currently.